# RegEx to strip out AD OU data in SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, regex

I have a script run that pulls AD data into a SharePoint list, this pulls the Line Manager field as:

**CN="Manager name",OU="1st OU",OU="2nd OU",OU="3rd OU",OU="4th OU",DC="FQDN"**

However I want to then copy that data into a new list but only keeping the *"Manager Name"* This will need to be done in a SharePoint designer 2013 Workflow.

I know the regex that'll work is **(?<=CN=)(.*?)(?=\,)** but I can't work out how to get that into a SharePoint Workflow to actually work!

*Any help would be great.*

Comment: Hi Simon, could you be able to rewrite your question for adding that the regex has to be set up in a SharePoint Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 2013 Workflows you can write a custom web service that take two arguments (inputs) and then send you back the string value as output. And then you have to Call it using Call http web service Action.

Note that this will only work for Sharepoint 2013 workflow but not for 2010 Workflow.